# Customize UIkit tooltip

Tags: css, uikit

I'm trying to set a customized uikit tooltip for my checkbox. I have changed the font color and background color. But I could change the font size. I've tried to add a custom class also but it didn't work. Is it possible to change the font size?

here is my code

```
<Checkbox label='Virtual' uk-tooltip="test text" />

.uk-tooltip.uk-active {
    color: yellow !important;
    font-size: 0.5rem !important;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Set font-size for uk-tooltip-inner class:

```
.uk-tooltip-inner {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```